# Deref a Arc<RwLock<T>> to return RwLockReadGuard<T> by default

Tags: rust, lifetime, ownership

I have the following wrapper for `Arc<RwLock<T>>`, and I would like to deref them to return the `RwLockReadGuard<T>` by default.

```rust
use anyhow::{Result, bail};
use serde::{Deserialize, Serialize};
use std::ops::Deref;
use std::sync::{Arc, Mutex, RwLock, RwLockReadGuard, RwLockWriteGuard};

#[derive(Serialize, Deserialize, Debug, Clone, Default)]
pub struct ArcRwLock<T: Sized>(Arc<RwLock<T>>);

impl<T> ArcRwLock<T> {
    pub fn new(data: T) -> Self {
        ArcRwLock(Arc::new(RwLock::new(data)))
    }

    pub fn write(&self) -> Result<RwLockWriteGuard<T>> {
        match self.0.try_write() {
            Ok(x) => Ok(x),
            Err(e) => {
                bail!(
                    "RwLock cannot acquire writer lock, error: {}",
                    e.to_string()
                )
            }
        }
    }

    pub fn read(&self) -> RwLockReadGuard<T> {
        self.0.read().unwrap()
    }

}

// impl<T: Sized> Deref for ArcRwLock<T> {
//     type Target = RwLockReadGuard<T>;

//     #[inline]
//     fn deref(&self) -> &Self::Target {
//         self.0.read().unwrap()
//     }
// }

impl<T: PartialEq> PartialEq for ArcRwLock<T> {
    fn eq(&self, other: &Self) -> bool {
        if Arc::ptr_eq(&self.0, &other.0) && ::core::ptr::eq(&*self.0, &*other.0) {
            true
        } else {
            *other.0.read().unwrap().deref() == *self.0.read().unwrap().deref()
        }
    }
}
```

I wrote the above wrapper mainly for the `PartialEq` I need for a parent struct to correctly `#[derive(PartialEq)]`.

**Most of the time I'm reading the values `T` from `Arc<RwLock<T>>`, writing to it is rare.**

The above implementation allows me to read/write the values using:

```rust
some_arc_object.write()?.uuid = Uuid::new_v4();
let updated_uuid: T = some_arc_object.read().uuid;
// where uuid is a field of T
```

Since I'm reading the properties most of the time, I'd like to get rid of the repeated `.read()` and achieve the following by Dereferencing the entire Arc<RwLock>:

```rust
let updated_uuid: T = some_arc_object.uuid;
// instead of having to add .read()
// let updated_uuid: T = some_arc_object.read().uuid;
```

My current humble attempt is shown above in the commented section, trying to make `deref()` work the same way `.read()` does. But the compiler is not happy with returning a reference of a local variable. Is there any chance it could be achieved, either by some lifetime magic or other workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dereferences by design should only resolve smart pointers to the pointee, see e.g. the [Rust API Guidelines](https://rust-lang.github.io/api-guidelines/predictability.html#only-smart-pointers-implement-deref-and-derefmut-c-deref). Acquiring a synchronization guard like `MutexGuard` or `RwLockReadGuard` in the `Deref` definitely goes beyond this guideline and could cause subtle bugs. I.e. you can get implicit locking of a resource without ever explicitly calling `lock()`, `read()` or `write()` on it because it's hidden in the `Deref` impl which implicitly gets called when resolving a method call.

As for the reasoning *why* it's not possible: `Deref`'s return type is a reference, thus you need to return something that you can turn into a reference from `deref()`. The `RwLockReadGuard` is a value that you're creating inside the `deref()` scope, thus it's dropped at the end of the scope, which in turn means you're not allowed to hand out a reference to it.

Sometimes it can be ergonomic to wrap whatever you need to do with the value inside the `RwLock` inside a function, i.e. if it's a `String` that sometimes gets written to but most of the time you just want to read it, define some convenience method like the following:

```
struct Foo {
    shared: Arc<RwLock<String>>,
}
impl Foo {
    fn get_shared_str(&self) -> String {
        self.shared.read().unwrap().clone()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I did not know about the API guidelines, and upon reading it, I do realize the problem of deref-ing into a Guard. But can I deref the entire thing into &T then? It would also allow me to directly use `some_arc_object.uuid` and doesn't seem to violate the guideline.?

Comment: Dereferencing through a `RwLock` to `&T` is not possible because that's the very thing `RwLock` and `Mutex` are preventing! Access is only possible when the synchronization primitive allows it. Thus, only `RwLockReadGuard` or `MutexGuard` **can** deref into `&T` and you need to acquire them through explicit access methods